# lubridate date-time interval behavior - finding single dates within intervals

Tags: r, date, lubridate

Running some tests to figure out how to use the `lubridate` library class of `interval` to solve a problem.

Is there a simple way to check if a single date/time is within a given interval?  All I have come up with so far is to convert the single date to an interval where the single date is repeated as start and end time and then test it like this.  Just wondering if there's a better way:

```
library(lubridate)
intTest <- mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:57", 
     tz = "America/New_York") %--% mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:59", 
     tz = "America/New_York")

int_overlaps(interval(mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58", 
 tz = "America/New_York"), mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58")), intTest)
```

Tried using `%within%` as well but that didn't work for this scenario either (unless I was using it wrong somehow).  Tried the test example given here, but it returns `FALSE` even though the answer is `TRUE`:

```
interval(mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58"), mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58"))  
         %within% intTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just

```
mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58", tz = "America/New_York") %within% intTest
#[1] TRUE
```

This is discussed on the `?"%within%"` help page, showing `a %within% b` where

> "a: An interval *or date-time object*"

Make sure you match your timezones too when doing comparisons.

```
intTest
#[1] 2017-05-20 02:28:57 EDT--2017-05-20 02:28:59 EDT

myint <- interval(
  mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58", tz="America/New_York"),
  mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58", tz="America/New_York")
)

myint
#[1] 2017-05-20 02:28:58 EDT--2017-05-20 02:28:58 EDT

myint %within% intTest
#[1] TRUE

myintUTC <- interval(
  mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58"),
  mdy_hms("5/20/2017 2:28:58")
)

myintUTC
#[1] 2017-05-20 02:28:58 UTC--2017-05-20 02:28:58 UTC

myintUTC %within% intTest
#[1] FALSE
```

Comment: The cause of my problem was just that it needed the format string when feeding the date into `%within%`.  Help on RStudio actually said "a is interval, b is interval", so now I will know that help pages may be more up-to-date then waht is in my R environment.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  Having a weird hard to replicate issue where the columns of a dataframe created using this technique, if I summarise to get their `max()` and  `min()` values and then try to subtract min from max in another column of the df, the result displays with the correct number but it says mins when it should be seconds.  Is there a way I need format this when performing operations on df columns (that were created using mdy_hms())?  I can't find an example that doesn't just show that i should be able to take max(), min() & subtract them like this: max(date_col) - min(date_col)`.

Comment: @TMWP - maybe `difftime(max(x), min(x), units="secs")` - you can specify what units you want for the `?difftime` operation

Comment: Thanks so much.  For readers on here: the oddity is that the date columns of my dataframe have values that differ by minutes or seconds.  For some reason, without the "secs" format, I was having a 6 second answer appear as "6.0000 mins".  Unfortunately, this fix means that some answers that are 15+ minutes apart now appear as 991 seconds which is hard to read but so long as the answer is right, that's still an improvement.  This behavior is very strange but the workaround suggested works.